# Why Proc python instead of proc fcmp when using SAS

Tags: python, sas

I am using the python module with pandas in proc fcmp when i want to implement some sas code with python.
Now i learned in a webinar that for viya21 there is a new feature called proc python to implement python code inside sas. After the webinar and some quick research i saw that the implementation with proc python is a bit less complicated, but i could not see any bigger advantage or functionality which could not be implemented by proc fcmp with python. Before I take the efford to set up a newer Viya21-Environment to test for myself, i wanted to know if it is worth it only for proc python.

So what are the advantages and reasons to use proc python instead of proc fcmp, assuming having an environment which supports both.

Comment: This is a bit more of an opinion, but PROC PYTHON is a full Python IDE within SAS Studio and includes things like syntax highlighting. Additionally, you can go to Pandas Dataframes and back to SAS fluidly with the sd2df and df2sd functions, similar to how you can go from the Data Step and SQL fluidly. The primary advantage is the ease of use and full integration to run entire Python programs.

Comment: You're looking at the evolution of a language/support as well. PROC FCMP is more generic and links to a set up installation of Python. Viya has it all in one making it much easier to work with Python than FCMP.  As support for Python is added, improvements are being made, PROC PYTHON is an example of that. One thing to check, which I can't easily find an answer to is which python installation executes the commands. With FCMP it seems like it's passed to a separate Python installation, whereas Viya allows for a centralized Python installation. So seems like its easier to administer in Viya.